# Shadow mapping with multiple shadows

Tags: c++, c, opengl, mapping, shadow

I've implemented shadow mapping using ARB extensions following this tutorial
http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/smt/smt.html
I've modified the code to add another light source. I've created and initialized 2 more matrices (lightViewMatrix2 and lightProjectionMatrix2) and another shadowMap texture.
At step 3 of the tutorial, after binding the first shadowmap texture, I've binded the second one. 
The result I get is that I see only the intersections between the 2 shadows produced by the 2 different light sources.
I've initialized all the matrices in the init function as shown in the tutorial, this is my display function.

```
void Display(void){
//First pass - from light's point of view
//Calculate & save matrices LIGHT 1
glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(  lightPosition[0], lightPosition[1], lightPosition[2],
                0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, lightViewMatrix);
glPopMatrix();

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(lightProjectionMatrix);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(lightViewMatrix);

//Use viewport the same size as the shadow map
glViewport(0, 0, shadowMapSize, shadowMapSize);

//Draw back faces into the shadow map
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

//Disable color writes, and use flat shading for speed
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glColorMask(0, 0, 0, 0);

//Draw the scene
DrawScene();

//Read the depth buffer into the shadow map texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowMapTexture[0]);
glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, shadowMapSize, shadowMapSize);


//First pass - from light's point of view
//Calculate & save matrices LIGHT 2
glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(  lightPosition2[0], lightPosition2[1], lightPosition2[2],
                0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, lightViewMatrix2);
glPopMatrix();

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(lightProjectionMatrix2);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(lightViewMatrix2);

//Use viewport the same size as the shadow map
glViewport(0, 0, shadowMapSize, shadowMapSize);

//Draw the scene
DrawScene();

//Read the depth buffer into the shadow map texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowMapTexture[1]);
glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, shadowMapSize, shadowMapSize);

//restore states
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glColorMask(1, 1, 1, 1);


//2nd pass - Draw from camera's point of view
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(cameraProjectionMatrix);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(cameraViewMatrix);

glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

float white2[3]={0.2f,0.2f,0.2f};

//light to represent shadowed areas
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, VECTOR4D(lightPosition));
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, white2);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, white2);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, black1);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

DrawScene();


//3rd pass
//Draw with bright light LIGHT1
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, white1);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, white1);

//Calculate texture matrix for projection
//This matrix takes us from eye space to the light's clip space
//It is postmultiplied by the inverse of the current view matrix when specifying texgen
static MATRIX4X4 biasMatrix(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                            0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);    //bias from [-1, 1] to [0, 1]

MATRIX4X4 textureMatrix=biasMatrix*lightProjectionMatrix*lightViewMatrix;

//Set up texture coordinate generation.
glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(0));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);

glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_T, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(1));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

glTexGeni(GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_R, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(2));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);

glTexGeni(GL_Q, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_Q, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(3));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

//Bind & enable shadow map texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowMapTexture[0]);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Enable shadow comparison
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE_ARB, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);

//Shadow comparison should be true (ie not in shadow) if r<=texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC_ARB, GL_LEQUAL);

//Shadow comparison should generate an INTENSITY result
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE_ARB, GL_INTENSITY);

//Set alpha test to discard false comparisons
glAlphaFunc(GL_GEQUAL, 0.99f);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

DrawScene();

//3rd pass
//Draw with bright light LIGHT2

MATRIX4X4 textureMatrix2=biasMatrix*lightProjectionMatrix2*lightViewMatrix2;

//Set up texture coordinate generation.
glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix2.GetRow(0));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);

glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_T, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix2.GetRow(1));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

glTexGeni(GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_R, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix2.GetRow(2));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);

glTexGeni(GL_Q, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_Q, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix2.GetRow(3));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

//Bind & enable shadow map texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowMapTexture[1]);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Enable shadow comparison
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE_ARB, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);

//Shadow comparison should be true (ie not in shadow) if r<=texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC_ARB, GL_LEQUAL);

//Shadow comparison should generate an INTENSITY result
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE_ARB, GL_INTENSITY);

//Set alpha test to discard false comparisons
glAlphaFunc(GL_GEQUAL, 0.99f);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

DrawScene();

//Disable textures and texgen
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

//Restore other states
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);


//Set matrices for ortho
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

//reset matrices
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();

glFinish();
glutSwapBuffers();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is you are first generating the shadow map for the first light, then you are generating a shadow map for the second light at the same time doing comparisons with the first shadow map. As a result you end up with a shadow that is some kind of combination of the two.
You would need to generate your second shadow the same way you generate your first (shadow generation for each light should be independent of every other light) and then finally since you would need to use some multi-texturing to somehow do the same comparison check for each z-texture independently.

Consider using a shader-based approach as all these fixed-function calls are outdated and have no advantage over shaders. The best article I read about shadow mapping with many lights is "Massive Number of Shadow-Casting Lights with Layered Rendering" By Daniel Rákos. It presents a very efficient way of doing this.